# CoreData sorting in fetch way slower than sorting after fetch?

Tags: sqlite, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Ive been trying to debug a CoreData fetch being extremely slow, the sqlite table has only 1900 records and it is taking 1.7 seconds to do the fetch. I have eliminated the predicate completely so it comes down to the sorting.

If I sort in the fetch request like so it take 1.7 seconds.

```
    // 1.7 seconds
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateRaised" ascending:NO],
                                [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"clientCreatedAt" ascending:NO]];
    items = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

If I fetch first then do an array sort it takes 0.2 seconds.

```
    // 0.2 seconds
    items = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    items = [items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateRaised" ascending:NO],
                                                [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"clientCreatedAt" ascending:NO]]];
```

Why is this, and what can I do to improve the CoreData fetch?

Comment: Do you have any indexes? (For this query, a compound index would be optimal.)

Comment: I haven't added any extra indexes beyond those CoreData adds automatically. I would be surprised to see indexes mattering much for 1900 rows though, that is a tiny table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out.

My object had a data field which in some cases contained a large blob of data. This absolutely kills sorting in Sqlite. I'm not entirely sure why it is so inefficient at this, but it is terrible.

Sorting after the fetch in Objective-C land is much faster. It just reorders the object references without actually moving any data around.

Comment: Check the "allows external storage" in the Core Data editor to make fetching with Binary Data fast again. :)